# R - computation doesn't return correct answer of 0

Tags: r

In RStudio, I key the following into the console:

```
0.1*0.1 - 0.01
```

This should give a value of 0. Instead, I get:

```
[1] 1.734723e-18
```

I get that this is essentially 0, but for my purposes, I need absolute accuracy. Why is this happening?

Comment: "I need absolute accuracy" -- then don't use floating point numbers

Comment: interesting ... `1/10 * 1/10 - 0.01` gives `0`

Comment: *absolute* precision is more or less impossible unless you work strictly with symbolic manipulation (what are you going to do about irrational or transcendental numbers ...?) Doesn't look like there's a [decimal floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) capability within R ... have you considered Python?

Comment: You could perhaps look into using the [Rmpfr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/Rmpfr-pkg.pdf)